# How to catch call intent from Htc Hero Dialer

Tags: android

Has anyone found a way to catch outgoing calls from the Htc Hero Dialer?

I currently use the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent in my app and this works for the standard Android dialer but not for the Htc Hero one. The hero dialer seems to not fire that specific intent.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I am unable to receive the same notification HTC Dezire as well?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem on HTC's build number 2.73.405.5 I have one Hero with that build number and another one with an earlier build number and it works on the earlier build number.

There were reports that HTC left out some code in the build and initially told users not to update but then retracted this so there may been some flaw in the HTC build.

Have you had any luck since posting this?

Comment: I currently have a workaround in place, but it is very ugly. 

I have a PhoneStateListener that acts on onCallStateChanged of the android telephony stack. When the state is CALL_STATE_OFHOOK I end the current call and then do my thing.

This way the Hero callscreen comes up for 1second and then aborts that call. Not pretty for the user :(